# Boolean expression in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have two ints: `@RecurremceTemp` and `@WeekDifference`

The following line errors:

```
PRINT @WeekDifference >= @RecurrenceTemp
```

with `Incorrect syntax near '>'`

And won't execute.

Can someone please tell me how to write such a boolean expression to include in a Select statement i.e.:

```
Select * 
FROM TableX 
WHERE somevariable = x 
and @WeekDifference >= @RecurrenceTemp
```

Comment: it seems this question get asked too much: Which RDBMS?

Comment: Works fine on SQL Server

Comment: Thanks Mitch, possibly the most useless comment ever.  Thanks to everyone else who took equal amounts of time in writing their answers.  Much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query ought to work just fine.

The reason that the `print` statement fails is due to the fact that SQL Server treats the results of a boolean expressions very differently than other data types.  See [Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846(SQL.80).aspx):

> Unlike other SQL Server data types, a
>   Boolean data type cannot be specified
>   as the data type of a table column or
>   variable, ***and cannot be returned in a
>   result set.***

Answer (score 2):

Predicates cannot be used in expressions, only in IF and WHILE and CASE WHEN:

```
PRINT CASE WHEN @WeekDifference >= @RecurrenceTemp THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Return -1, 0, or 1 from a CASE statement, depending on the comparison. In SQL Sevrer, there is no boolean data type. The nearest data type is `BIT`, which can have a value of 1, 0 or null.

**EDIT:**

Your SQL statement

```
Select * 
FROM TableX 
WHERE somevariable = x 
and @WeekDifference >= @RecurrenceTemp
```

will select all fields from TableX where somevariable = x and the WeekDifference variable value is greater than or equal to the RecurrenceTemp variable value. Is that not what you want?